# What is the term for the phrases that tell readers they are reading a citation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Several years ago, I took a college course that introduced a term for "phrases used when citing a text", but as the course was a few years ago, and I cannot find the lesson slides, I cannot remember the term used. It might be something like "tags".

I am not looking for words like "cite", "give attribution", but an actual noun and name for these types of phrases:

Examples: "**According to...**", "**The author claims...**", "**The author contends...**", "**The passage reiterates that...**", are all examples of this type of phrase.

Without this language: "The Earth is 40,075 km in circumference."

With this language: "**According to White (2017),** the Earth is 40,075 km in circumference".

Without this language: "The Earth is not entirely round."

With this language: "**White (2017) claims that** the Earth is not entirely round".

Sample sentence: "The author used too much of the same _____ when citing his sources, he should have instead used much more variety, to keep the paper more interesting."

What term best refers to this?

Comment: Reference?  You haven't provided a sentence with a blank for how this would be used, so it's hard to figure out quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why you think there is a need for such a word?  If you cannot find a single word for a particular idea normally expressed by a phrase, it is probably because the idea does not come up in writing or conversation often enough to to make it necessary.  What will one word do that a brief phrase cannot?

Comment: @Tuffy I know the word exists, as it was covered in a course, and now I'm teaching a course with the same, want to pass on the terminology.

Comment: When you cite a text, you provide a citation. Nothing describes the content of a citation except the citation itself.

Comment: @Village You're starting to get some usable answers, but you still need to edit the original question to provide a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. Or, more accurately, you do provide one, but just need to make it clear: after the second example reference you could say "The phrase 'claims that' is another ____."

Comment: Maybe I'm too much of an IT guy used to thinking in indirections, but I think the question title is misleading: "According to" and "claims" are not *referring to **citations***, they are referring to **works.** This reference is called a *citation!* (An example where somebody refers to a citation could be "the alleged references Smith provides for his claims turned out to be mostly fictitious.") I'd say the proper title would be "What is the term for the language used to refer to the source in a citation?

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks for editing, but that just turned a rather-complicated 5-year-old question into a very simple one. As it currently stands... you're just looking for the word *for attributions*, citations, or references, not a word *for the phrases one uses when making such references*. If you intended the latter, it needs a bit of editing again. Please note, the instructions for the tag single-word-request say: "To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: No, I'm not looking for attributions, citations, or references. The word I was looking for is "Attributive tags".

Comment: Then, to avoid attracting future bad answers, as questions live on beyond your personal need for them, *please edit* to make that clear.

Comment: Note that 'The author claims/argues/contends/...' are far more modal in character (ie suggesting that the author may well not be right) than say 'The author writes ...'.

Comment: The full OED definition **B** for **attributive** - ***(noun)** An attributive word, **one that denotes an attribute.** Applied by Harris and others to adjectives, verbs, and adverbs; by most modern grammarians only to adjectives and their equivalents* (but obviously they didn't intend to exclude multi-word *noun **phrases*** used adjectivally). In the right context, plain ***attributive*** would be fine - it doesn't *need* an explicit "head noun" *attributive **tag / phrase / clause / element***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the term "attribution tags". This wouldn't include the works cited (nor the parenthetical citation in some cases), as that's not a [tag](https://web.archive.org/web/20201126035218/https://www.lexico.com/web/20201126035218/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tag) (see the *grammar* definition). It would include "according to *X*", as mentioned in some of the sources I found.  Searching brings up a number of synonyms:

- Attributive tags
- [Signal phrases](https://www2.latech.edu/%7Ebmagee/louisiana_anthology/texts/penn-warren/penn-warren--all_the_kings_men--lesson_plans_files/Lesson%2018%20Writing%20the%20Essay/Attributive%20Tags.pptx)
- [Author tags](https://writingcenterunderground.wordpress.com/tag/attributive-tags/)

Less specifically it is called "attribution", or sometimes even "words of attribution", according to the [University of Kansas](https://web.ku.edu/%7Eedit/attribute.html) (which also uses "attribution tag"). Arguably that would include the works cited section and [parenthetical citations](https://uscmed.sc.libguides.com/c.php?g=484371&p=3313015) too. "[Verbs of attribution](https://www.centralia.edu/resources/docs/verbsatrib.pdf)" is used to refer to an obvious subset of such words.

And there are some [terms used of non-academic writing](https://medium.com/the-1000-day-mfa/how-to-write-dialogue-attribution-4b4137a6e9fd), which are used when it's dialogue:

- Dialogue tags (e.g. "she said")
- Beats (when a character's action is used instead of a dialogue tag)
- Dialogue attribution (a hypernym including both)

Answer (score 1):

**citation language**

> Each of these types of composition follows a well-defined form, so
> that, if we were given only an account in abstract terms of the
> arrangement of subject and predicate or a simple account of the
> selection of **citation language** (e.g., "**as it is said**," "**our Rabbis
> have taught**,") we could readily predict the purpose of the composition
> or composite. [Jacob Neusner; *The Talmud*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Talmud/pRttAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> **Goals**
>
> By the end of the project, students will
>
> - ...
> - orally refer to sources using "**citation language**"  [Adrian Gras-Velazquez; *Project-Based Learning in Second Language Acquisition*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Project_Based_Learning_in_Second_Languag/6WClDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22&pg=PT45&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> Compare as well CD 16:6-9, where Deut. 23:24 is cited at the beginning
> of a series of scriptureless rules regarding oaths and vows (including
> CD 16:10-12, where **citation language** is used to introduce an
> allusion to Num. 30:9), as might have been the case for CD 9:8-10
> (where the citation is not of an actual scriptural verse). [M. Stone
> and E. Chazon; *Biblical Perspectives*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Biblical_Perspectives_Early_Use_and_Inte/3sN5DSodzoMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22&pg=PA71&printsec=frontcover) (1998)
>
> [I believe *CD* refers to a copy of the Damascus Document (one of the Dead Sea Scrolls) found in the Cairo genizah (synagogue storeroom) collection.]

> Samraj's investigation revealed that, compared to the RA writers, the
> student thesis writers had more frequent use of the integral citation
> type... Similary, the students, again in comparison to the published
> writers, had more frequent use of "verb controlled" integral
> citations..., whereby the source author took on the "agent" role as the subject of the verb in the student's sentence... rather than just being "named" in a less prominent position in the sentence...
>
> In another study of graduate student's source citations, Pecorari
> (2006) also used a manual approach, which this time revealed ways that
> the students' **citation language** *transgressed* norms of course use
> for research genres. [Sunny Hyon; *Introducing Genre and English for
> Specific Purposes*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introducing_Genre_and_English_for_Specif/kaQ5DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22%20verbs&pg=PT81&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> Notwithstanding the long-noted similarities between **citation
> language** in early rabbinic midrash and Qumran exegesis, most
> commonly employing a form of the verbs רמא, and בתכ, we find nothing
> in Qumranic antecedents to  ... [Michael Satlow; *Strength to
> Strength*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Strength_to_Strength/mumADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22%20verbs&pg=PA284&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> This emerging interest has given us detailed understanding of specific
> aspects of **citation language**, for example verb tense, thematic
> choice, voice, and the name of the cited author ... [*Australian
> Review of Applied Linguistics*, Vol. 20, p. 51](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22citation%20language%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJcQYXa8YsLHFSk5_kVdcWWEZLGjg:1639417944050&ei=WIi3Yd_PAqfPytMP_4qroAo&start=50&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjf28Xhq-H0AhWnp3IEHX_FCqQ4KBDy0wN6BAgBEEU&biw=933&bih=493&dpr=1.5) (1997) (Snippet
> View)

> Communicating research through an RA
>
> - Command of schematic structure
> - Command of discipline specific **citation language** and metadiscourse
> - Command of generic writing skills such as argument and coherence. [Ken Hyland; *Academic Publishing Issues and Challenges in the
>   Construction of Knowledge*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Academic_Publishing_Issues_and_Challenge/j9enCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22&pg=PT294&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

> In addition to studies that have analyzed the content and critical
> thinking aspects of novice history writer's texts, researchers have
> earmarked the following **genre features** as signifying competencies
> of more advanced writers in the the discipline: the use of *multiple
> source texts* to support a point...; the *use of source texts in
> multiple ways*...; ***citation language** that contextualizes and
> analyzes the source*, and use of organizing structures and causal
> connecting words that result in *causal arguments*...  [Anne Beufort;
> *College Writing and Beyond*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/College_Writing_and_Beyond/cmngCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22&pg=PT81&printsec=frontcover) (2008)

> In doing so, they analyzed "how five students responded to four
> document-based questions over a year, tracing how organization,
> document use and **citation language** indicate the degree to which
> writers transformed and integrated information in disciplinary ways".
> [S. Totten and J. Pederson; *Educating Abut Social Issues in the 20th
> and 21st Centuries*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Educating_About_Social_Issues_in_the_20t/8AQoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22citation%20language%22&pg=PA113&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

Comment: Are you sure that "citation language" in all of these means the phrasing used when giving attribution in text and not what's in the works cited nor the language the citation is in (eg English)?

Comment: @Laurel I did realize the other uses (including a legal *citation* for something criminal), but rereading I think you are correct and I removed the ambiguous ones for which I didn't have access to clarifying surrounding text. -- Thank you! I'll try to add others.

Comment: Yeah, the uses that survived after editing are pretty clear. I'm not sure whether they constitute an established term (the scare quotes might count against it), but they clearly serve the purpose.

Comment: @AndyBonner That could just be the author introducing a term they think the reader may not be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

"Attribute" is nice and formal. But I don't think it's ideal for your purposes.

There are other candidates: "credit", "impute", "assign" spring to mind. Or my personal favourite, "ascribe".

"This theory of the ingestion of bleach to cure Covid-19 has been *ascribed* to a man who is the most orange person to date to have been President of the United States".

So, what is the difference between "attribute" and "ascribe"? According to [this page](https://wikidiff.com/ascribe/attribute), "ascribe" is used more with people, whereas "attribute" is more commonly used with *causes*. I'm not sure I agree with that entirely. However, have a look at the citations on that page: it does appear that "attribute" is broader in scope.

Since you say "when someone", I'd say "ascribe" is very marginally preferable.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! I'm afraid the OP is looking, not for a word that attributes, but for *a label for the category of phrases that attribute*. It's unfortunate that they haven't provided a sample sentence that would clear this up.