# Does the sentence "'This time, you won't get away,' squinted the man" make sense?

Tags: grammar, literature

Usually, in literature they would use a myriad of words for "said" after quoting what the man says. Is using a different verb, like "squinted," correct in literature?

Comment: Closely related: [He nodded his head 'Yes' / She shook her head 'No'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/he-nodded-his-head-yes-she-shook-her-head-no/165866#165866). I don't think Visser mentions 'squint' as a newly appearing quotative verb.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139524/discussion-on-question-by-holylulu-does-the-sentence-this-time-you-wont-get). If you want to discuss this question, please go there. Note that further discussion comments here cannot be migrated, so they are likely simply to be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, your example is very unusual

You're trying to use a dialogue tag with a word (*squinted*) that's just not used in dialogue tags. You have to either use a rough synonym of "said" or make it a separate sentence so it's an action beat.

#### Dialogue Tags

Dialogue tags are of the form "she said". They can be inverted ("said Melissa" — inversion pretty much requires a noun) or use any one of the synonyms for "said" ("she shouted", "she whispered"). Significantly, they are *tags*, which means that they're in the same sentence as the dialogue (joined with a comma, unless the dialogue requires a question or exclamation mark):

> "I can't believe you'd do this," she said.

#### Action Beats

Dialogue doesn't have to have a tag, but back and forth with no indication of who said what can get confusing, so the paragraph that the dialogue is in will sometimes have a sentence in it describing what the speaker is doing:

> "Of course you would say that." He flung open the door.

Note that the dialogue ends in a period. The beat is its own sentence.

---

See also

- [My answer about attribution, tags, and beats](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/580058/191178), which has plenty of relevant references.
- [My COCA search for verbs after quotes](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=109529441). It's not a very accurate search (lots of irrelevant results) but it shows some of the verbs used in inverted dialogue tags: *said* is the most popular but you'll also see *replied*, *added*, and *declared*, among others. You can also see some verbs that mean "said in writing" (*wrote*, *reported*), which are popular in nonfiction like the news.

Comment: This is the grammatically-correct answer. Sven Yargs elaborated above that in practice there is much room to play with those tags. Do you agree?

Answer (score 2):

"'This time, you won't get away,' squinted the man."

Makes sense, if unusual and playful. The man's mere squint connotes a threat of entrapment of some other person. I don't think it's supposed to be interpreted as a verbal utterance but as a physical sign that connotes the idea of "This time, you won't get away."

I think that in this construction, "man" is in the nominative case to the intransitive verb "squint." It's not the verb's object since "to squint" is usually (but not always) intransitive.

"He *squinted* in order to see a distant object." [intransitive]
"He *squinted his eyes* so tightly that he could barely see." [transitive]

If you wanted to be tiresomely explicit, you could write,

"'This time, you won't get away,' the man's squint threatened."

It's correct but a bit stale. I prefer the original construction since it's *visual*.

Comment: This answer is the opposite of the most upvoted answer. My question refers to literature, and not to grammar. Am I to understand that the sentence is incorrect grammatically, but it could be used in certain literature without completely weirding out native speakers?

Comment: @holylulu On the contrary, it is correct grammatically but it is odd semantically. A squint normally conveys neither speech nor a threat (people squint because of bright sunlight or poor eyesight or because they have something in their eye), so having it accompany a threat is odd semantically, just as *"I love you very much", he threatened.* would be odd.

Comment: @holylulu: Grammatically / syntactically, *"Leave me alone!", squinted the man* is just as "valid" as *Colourless green ideas sleep furiously*. I suppose a poet *might* use ***to squint*** as a transitive "manner of speaking" verb - but that doesn't mean the usage would seem acceptable to his readers. And unquestionably, anyone who feels the need to *ask* whether they can write like this *shouldn't*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although this answer completes the first one, and is arguably what many writers would look for, I think your last point justifies picking the first. StuartF: Yep, I meant semantically, could not find the right word.

Comment: >A squint normally conveys neither speech nor a threat 

Clearly, it depends on the context.